# calculation on textboxes that have date value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three textboxes named `borrower_date_txt`,`period_txt` and `ret_date_txt`.

Now, I want to make calculation on those textboxes. I want to enter the date into the `borrower_date_txt` (not only today's date), and in the `period_txt` I enter a period for example 5. In the `ret_date_txt` I want to display the

```
borrower_date_txt + 5
```

i.e give me the date after 5 days of `borrower_date_txt` date value in the `ret_date_txt`?

Comment: Parse each `TextBox.Text` to a `DateTime` type object, using DateTime.Parse/DateTime.ParseExact etc. Then use DateTime.AddDays(5) to get a new DateTime object. Shouldn't be that difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime borrowerDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(borrower_date_txt.Text, out borrowerDate))
{
    int days;
    if (int.TryParse(period_txt.Text, out days))
    {
        var retDate = borrowerDate.AddDays(days);
        ret_date_txt.Text = retDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

The important parts of the above code are as follows:

- `DateTime.TryParse(...)`: this will return `false` if the text isn't a valid date; otherwise it will assign the `DateTime` value to the `borrowerDate`. This is a way of safe-guarding your code. Parsing dates can get much more complex quickly, but I'm thinking this will likely due for your situation.
- `int.TryParse(...)`: this will return `false` if the text isn't a valid integer; otherwise it will assign the `int` value to the `days`. This is a way of safe-guarding your code.
- `borrowerDate.AddDays(days)`: this actually adds the days entered to the date entered.
- `ret_date_txt.Text = retDate.ToShortDateString()`: this displays the result in the `ret_date_txt` text box, and formats it as a short date (i.e. without the time).

Comment: thank you Michael Perrenoud your answer is very helpful ... but know i have problem in borrower_date_txt i use date in (dd/M/yyyy) format and in the ret_date_txt it add the period with the month not a date ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can use the `DateTime.AddDays` method in order to increase a DateTime:

```
try
{
   DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(borrower_date_txt.Text);
   int period = Int32.Parse(period_txt.Text);
   ret_date_txt.Text = date.AddDays(period).ToShortDateString();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //Handle parsing errors maybe
}
```

Comment: how to can i use this ... please give me more details ... more codes

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Try/Catch, it would be faster to use TryParse for this.

Comment: Fast is a question of how many times should this code run? Think about it, this is a user's click, not a loop or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse your text boxes values to proper date time objects:

```
      DateTime Date1= DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Then you can perform all the relevant DateTime operations on Date1.